# DSC-Resource: How can I delete a registry key (not value)?

Tags: powershell, dsc

I know I can ensure the presens of a specific registry value by using the following scriptblock:

```
    Registry ConfigureRegistry
    {
        Ensure    = 'Present'
        Key       = 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\SomeKey'
        ValueName = 'MachineType'
        ValueData = 'Hyper-V'
    }
```

But how can I delete the registry key `SomeKey`? If I only change the keyword `Ensure = "Present"` to `Ensure = "Absent"` it will leave the key `SomeKey`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This is now possible, see VertigoRay's answer.](https://serverfault.com/a/907918/236470)

This isn't possible at the moment with the `Registry` resource, as you've discovered.

You can use a [`Script` resource](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn282130.aspx) or write a full custom resource instead.

Answer (score 3):

This is possible, [as documented](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/dsc/registryresource#properties):

> To add or remove a registry key, specify [ValueName] as an empty string without specifying ValueType or ValueData.

## Example

```
Registry ConfigureRegistry
{
    Ensure    = 'Absent'
    Key       = 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\SomeKey'
    ValueName = ''
}
```

PSDrives also work:

```
Registry ConfigureRegistry
{
    Ensure    = 'Absent'
    Key       = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\SomeKey'
    ValueName = ''
}
```